# JQuery noob - hover over one image, change another

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, hover

Now i have searched through google and youtube now. But I can't find the answer!

What I like to do..
I got a menu with a picture in the middle.
When I hover over a menu point, it turns blue and the picture in the middle also turns out blue.

The hover effect that changes the menu point, works through **CSS**. 
But I can't get the picture in the middle to change!

My html code:

```
<nav class="nav1">
  <ul> 
    <a href="news.html" class="but" id="news">News</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="but">index</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="but">about</a>
    <a href="media.html" class="but">Media</a>
    <a href="mons.html" target="_self"> 
    <img src="images/logo/logo.png"  class="knaplogo" id="logo">
    <-- THIS IS THE ONE WHO SHOULD CHANGE -->
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="butf"></a>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" class="buty"></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank" class="butt"></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and my query, for start i'm only trying it with one point:

```
$('#news').hover(function(){
  $('#logo').image('../images/logo/logo.png');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the attribute method:

```
$('#news').hover(function(){
    $('#logo').attr('src', '../images/logo/logo.png');
});
```

Comment: @user2254488 make sure the new image path is correct, and try to include the full URL of the image as relative path's couldn't work.

Comment: @user2254488 Absolute paths are definitely recommended as you can guarantee that it is pointing to the correct location. Also, going by the src of the image in your markup you want something more like `$('#logo').attr('src', 'images/logo/logo.png');`.

Comment: Hmm... The path is right, I have tried a absolute path. Still nothing...

Can it have something to do whit the html?
That I have a image src code, and it can't be changed because it stocked there.. Just a theory.